# Echo $JAVA_HOME returns empty despite being present in .bashrc, .bash_profile, .profile files

Tags: linux, bash, macos, export

I've added the following line in all 3 files:

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_121.jdk/Contents/Home
```

If I do, `echo $JAVA_HOME`, I get empty line as output.
If I do `source .bash_profile` and then do echo $JAVA_HOME, I get the output correctly.
If I close the terminal application and re-open the terminal app again, `echo $JAVA_HOME`shows empty again. Isn't .profile or .bash_profile supposed to load it to bash when I reopen? I added it to all 3 files to be sure. But it just doesn't seem to work

Note: I'm using Zsh on Mac. Does this have anything to do with what I'm facing?

Comment: Try .zprofile for zshell on Mac.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Thanks. It worked. Moving your solution to answers.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @JoachimIsaksson for the solution in the comments. I had to move stuff to .zprofile for zshell on Mac and it worked.